# UIBarButtonItem in navigationBar set Vertical Position Offset

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to move my UIBarButtonItem in the UINavigationBar "down". For that I'm using the following code:

```
[[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 10.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If I change 0.0f in the horizontal position to an arbitrary value, the text moves horizontal. But I can't change the vertical position. No matter what I enter for 10.0f, I see no effect.

Edit: I've added a UIView to my UINavigationar.
`[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:statusbarview];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment` for adjust your UIBarButton

As Per the docs

> This offset is used to adjust the vertical centering of bordered bar
>   buttons within the bar.

Here is the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617141-setbackgroundverticalpositionadj?language=objc)

and here is an example

```
[yourBarButton setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-10.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has also no effect. Maybe I have to add the Information, that I added a UIView to the Navigationbar? (`self.navigationController.navigationBar`)

Comment: in the `statusbarview` have you added button ?

Comment: No, on the UINavigationBar, but maybe it has an effect I thought

Comment: I am asking you have added UIView as UIBarButton, in that view have you added button ?

Comment: No. I add a UIBarButtonItem to my NavigationBar in the InterfaceBuilder. Later in the viewDidLoad, I add also a UIView to the NavigationBar